# What is the quality rate of intrinsic autoregulation in the heart?

Tags: physiology, cardiology, blood-circulation

Autoregulation is the maintenance of constant blood flow to an organ in spite of fluctuations in Blood pressure.
It involves the relaxation of myocardium and contraction.
It is local.

I know that autoregulation is best done in the brain, well in kidneys and badly in skeletal muscle.
I am interested how it is in the heart.
I think it should be at least good.
Brain can be thought more important.
However, I am not sure.

**How good is the autoregulation of the blood flow in the heart?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My conjecture**: Intrinsic regulation is done in the heart the second best, after the brain.
This idea is based on the fact that the brain controls heart's some autonomic functions.

It is an open research question how the autonomic nervous system affects the intrinsic functions of the heart - and the reverse is true too.

To answer this question, we need to understand the autonomic regulation of the heart better i.e. the inner-physiology of the heart's electrical activity.